# WPF. Как в MVVM стиле биндить ListViewItem к List<>?

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, binding

Как можно в рамках подхода MVVM реализовать binding каждого `ListViewitem`(объекта ListView) элемента к коллекции `IList<IElementProperty>`? То есть я хочу получить возможность динамически управлять числом полей-свойств в элементах `ListViewitem` объекта `ListView`. Очевидно, что тогда число столбцов будет определяться в ран-тайм в области модели представления. Все элементы для одного `ListView` предполагаются с одинаковой структурой, но определяемой в ран-тайме перед заполнением самого `ListView`.

Answer (score 1):

Для таких задач есть стадартные API:

- для динамического добавления свойств (а также методов и событий) - `ICustomTypeDescriptor`
- для динамической генерации столбцов лучше воспользоваться `DataGrid` и событием автогенерации столбцов. В нем вы можете создать несколько столбцов и определить Binding для них на "виртуальные" свойства вашего прокси-объекта. При этом WPF уже знает как работать с объектом, реализующим интерфейс ICustomTypeDescriptor, и установка свойств будет работать "сама по себе".